# How to model Player, Match, and EloRank as NDB entities

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I'm trying to wrap my head around entities groups and hierarchical keys in `ndb` but I might be stuck in "normalized thinking". I want to compute and store different players' rank based on how they did in different matches against each other over time. But all I can come up with is to store the "foreign keys" as strings like this:

```
class Player(ndb.Model):
     name = ndb.StringProperty()         

class Match(ndb.Model):
     player1_key = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Player) # pointing to Player entity
     player2_key = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Player) # pointing to Player entity
     player1_score = ndb.IntegerProperty()
     player2_score = ndb.IntegerProperty()
     time = ndb.DatetimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class EloRank(ndb.Model):
    player_key = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Player) # pointing to Player entity
    match_key = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Match) # pointing to Match entity
    rank = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    time = ndb.DatetimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

Sure, it would be easy to "denormalize" the data by copy it (i.e. Match have two sub keys, one for player 1 and one for player 2) but how can I for instance change name of a player without resorting to doing updates on each Match entity?
`StructuredProperty` doesn't seem to be the answer either, since they belong to the defining entity.

How would you rewrite this model to put the entities in the same group?

**Update**
Use `KeyProperty` instead of `StringProperty` as suggested by M12.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you may want to use the ndb.KeyProperty() to store player keys instead of a StringProperty().

If you store a reference (key) to the players participating in each match, you don't need to update every match when a user changes name, as when a match is requested by a user, the application could use the player's key to fetch their name and send it back to the user.

Next, I'd probably store the player's rank within his instance, i.e. in the Player model:

```
class Player(ndb.Model):
     name = ndb.StringProperty()
     rank = ndb.IntegerProperty()
```

This approach requires you to write a fairly solid framework that makes sure that after every match, all users scores are modified appropriately. The "per-match-score" could still be in the Match model, but the Player model would have the "aggregated" score of all matches played.

In order to do this, it would also be handy to add a list of matches played by each player into their model, so the Player model would now be:

```
class Player(ndb.Model):
     name = ndb.StringProperty()
     rank = ndb.IntegerProperty()
     matches = ndb.KeyProperty(repeated=True)
```

Player.matches would essentially be a list of keys to matches played by the user so that are easier to be fetched when looking at a Players details and history of matches played.

Alternatively, Player.matches could be a ndb.JsonProperty() if you would like to store additional information regarding matches played, as the one I initially suggested (ndb.KeyProperty(repeated=True)) is fairly limited in what it can store (it's only a list)

Hope this helps a bit!

Comment: Thanks. Yes, `KeyProperty` seems like a good idea but that will just give me a type check so that I only can assign Match keys to the matches property etc. What I was wondering about was how to "formulate" this model as an entity group.

Comment: You wouldnt as a Match is not owned by a single player. Each match would be its own group. It would make sense to have the Player then ancestor of EloRank - it belongs the the Players entity group, then the KeyProperty for Player is redundant.